# how do I add one to many relationship in hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate, jakarta-ee, hibernate-mapping

On the database, I have these two tables:

```
- Destination:
 - idDestination
 - name

- Airport:
 - idAirport
 - idDestination // FK into Destination city
 - name
```

where:

- 1 Destination(read: city) has many Airports
- 1 Airport belongs to 1 City
- Hence: 1-Many relation between Destination-Airports

---

My Java classes look like this:

```
class Destination{
 private Integer idDestination;
 private String name;

 // getter and setters
}

class Airport{
 private Integer idAirport;
 private Destination city;
 private String name;
}

// Separate class for airports in city, since city is being used in a lot of other places
// and I'd like to keep Destination class clean
class CityAirports{
 private Destination City;
 private Set<Airport> airports;
}
```

---

Hibernate Mappings: Airport.hbm.xml

```
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="org.wah.dao.Airport" table="AIRPORT">
        <id name="idAirport" type="java.lang.Integer">
            <column name="IDAIRPORT" />
            <generator class="identity" />
        </id>
        <property name="name" type="java.lang.String">
            <column name="NAME" />
        </property>
        <many-to-one name="city" class="org.wah.dao.Destination">
            <column name="IDCITY" />
        </many-to-one>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

---

I need to define another mapping for CityAirports to 
- retrieve all the airports within the city. 
- add a new airport to the city.

I am not sure what the hibernate mapping would look like ? Can someone please guide me on how to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for destination mapping,

```
<hibernate-mapping>
 <class name="org.wah.dao.Destination" table="DESTINATION">
 <id name="idDestination" type="int" column="DESTINATION_ID">
     <generator class="native" />
 </id>
 <property name="name" type="string" not-null="true" length="100" 
    column=DESTINATION_NAME" />
 <set name="destinationAirPorts" table="DESTINATION_AIRPORT" cascade="all">
  <key column="DESTINATION_ID" />
  <many-to-many column="IDAIRPORT" unique="true" class="org.wah.dao.Airport" />
 </set>
</class>
```

for airport mapping,

```
<hibernate-mapping>
 <class name="org.wah.dao.Airport" table="AIRPORT">
 <id name="idAirport" type="int" column="IDAIRPORT">
     <generator class="native" />
 </id>
 <property name="name" type="string" not-null="true" length="100" 
    column=NAME" />

</class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Comment: couple of things.. 1. should the root of mapping be for `CityAirports` class ? 2. I don't have a table by the name of DESTINATION_AIRPORT. Can you add some comments on how this would work ?

Comment: We have one mapping file per class. But, you've defined two mappings here. I'm a little confused on how this would work ?

Comment: I use many-to-many element to create the one-to-many relationship between the Destination and Airport entities. Since a destination can have any number of airports we use a collection to hold the values. In this case we use Set. Many-to-many element is usually used to create many-to-many relationship, here we place the unique constraint on the IDAIRPORT column, this makes the relationship one-to-many.

Answer (score 0):

Read the example mentioned [here](http://www.vaannila.com/hibernate/hibernate-example/hibernate-mapping-one-to-many-1.html) which describes the solution you are looking for neatly.
Basic idea is that you use many-to-many relationship from city-to-airport and place unique constraint on IDAIRPORT

Comment: CityAirports doesn't really have a table in database for itself. So, when we need to add a city, it needs to update the Destination table. When a airport is added to city, it needs to update Airports table. For reading, we need to do something similar. The tutorial you mentioned has a specific table for this sort of a relationship. How do I do the mapping when there is not one dedicated table for that class ?

Answer (score 0):

Could be something like this ??

```
<class name="org.wah.dao.CityAirports">
        <id name="caID">
            <generator class="assigned" />
        </id>

        <set name="Airport" cascade="save-update" >
            <key column="apID" />
            <one-to-many class="org.wah.dao.Airport" />
        </set>
        <many-to-one name="city" class="org.wah.dao.Destination">
            <column name="IDCITY" />
        </many-to-one>

</class>
```

Comment: What is caID for the id you mentioned?

Comment: there is no CityAirport table. It references the Destination and airport table in db.

Comment: Hey, is there anything in your destination table that maps to Airport ?

Comment: Airport table has an Foreign Key id which references the destination (read: city) table.

Answer (score 0):

Is the `CityAirport` class really necessary? Why not just put a list of `Airport`s into your `Destination`?

Not sure about the .xml configuration for this. But using annotations, you would get something like this:

```
@Entity
public class Destination {
   @Id
   @GeneratedValue
   private Integer idDestination;

   private String name;
   @OneToMany(mappedBy="destination")
   Set<Airport> airports;
    [...]
}
```

And the Airport class:

```
@Entity
public class Airport {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Integer id;

    @ManyToOne
    private Destination destination;
    [...]
}
```

Comment: I am using Destination in a number of places and would like to follow encapsulation and keep it clean. Thanks for the annotations, but can you also help me out with the use case of CityAirports ?

Comment: From my knowledge, your approach is not solvable. Could be wrong though - you want automatically updated fields on a class which is not even persisted in your database. 
From an encapsulation point of view I'd say the Set<Airport> approach does not really violate any paradigms or restrictions. If you fear that all the airports are loaded into memory whenever you load a destination, fear not - hibernate supports lazy loading

Comment: Well, Destination and Airports persist in the backend database as separate tables and even have foreign key relations. The Java class implies the relation, City->Airport, where a city contains multiple airports. For traversing in opposite direction, i.e. Airport serves which city, I have it identified by having a `Destination` object in Airport class. Also, see airport.hbm.xml in the question I posted above.